# Cannot control the value of opacity

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I have a Class level boolean variable which speaks with all the classes and widget in each class change depending on weather or not this value is true. Opacity is throwing the below error when I try to execute. I've tried AsyncImages but it given a loading logo which I am trying to avoid.

Below is the snippet of the code

Python File:

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass
class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    ABS_OPACITY=BooleanProperty(True)           
    def test(self):
        print "Hello"
    def build(self):
        return presentation
```

Kivy file -

```
ScreenManagement:
    MainScreen: 
    SecondScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "Main"
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            font_size:12
            size_hint: 0.07, 0.05
            text: "AC"
            on_click:app.ABS_OPACITY=not app.ABS_OPACITY
            pos_hint: {"right":0.93,"left":0.30, "bottom":0.1, "top": 0.93}
        Image:
            source: "xyz/image.png"
            pos_hint:{"top":0.955}
            opacity:1 if app.ABS_OPACITY else 0
        Image:
            source: "abc/image.png"
            pos_hint:{"top":0.955}
            opacity:0 if app.ABS_OPACITY else 1

<SecondScreen>:
    name: "Second"
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            font_size:12
            size_hint: 0.07, 0.05
            text: "AC"
            on_click:on_click:app.ABS_OPACITY=not app.ABS_OPACITY
            pos_hint: {"right":0.93,"left":0.30, "bottom":0.1, "top": 0.93}
        Image:
            source: "xyz/image"
            pos_hint:{"top":0.955}
            opacity:1 if app.ABS_OPACITY else 0
        Image:
            source: "abc/image.png"
            pos_hint:{"top":0.955}
            opacity:0 if app.ABS_OPACITY else 1
```

The above is the error I am facing when I do the same..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "testapp.py", line 412, in <module>
     presentation = Builder.load_file ("main.kv")
   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 405, in load_string
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 657, in _apply_rule
     root=rctx['ids']['root'], rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 469, in apply_class_lang_rules
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 538, in apply
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 707, in _apply_rule
     e), cause=tb)
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "/home/pi/Downloads/motormind/main.kv", line 161:
 ...
     159:           source: "UI_UX/blue/mainpage/abs.png"
     160:           pos_hint:{"top":0.955}
 >>  161:           opacity:0 if app.ABS_OPACITY else 1
     162:       #Park Lights On
     163:       Image:
 ...
 BuilderException: Parser: File "/home/pi/Downloads/motormind/main.kv", line 161:
 ...
     159:           source: "UI_UX/blue/mainpage/abs.png"
     160:           pos_hint:{"top":0.955}
 >>  161:           opacity:0 if app.ABS_OPACITY else 1
     162:       #Park Lights On
     163:       Image:
 ...
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'
   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 249, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "/home/pi/Downloads/motormind/main.kv", line 161, in <module>
     opacity:0 if app.ABS_OPACITY else 1
   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 75, in __getattribute__
     object.__getattribute__(self, '_ensure_app')()
   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 70, in _ensure_app
     app.bind(on_stop=lambda instance:

   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 692, in _apply_rule
     rctx['ids'])
   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 254, in create_handler
     cause=tb
```

Comment: Please post a minimal runnable example.

Answer (score 0):

This error is typical of calling `Builder.load_file()` for a `kv` file that is creating Widgets and referencing the `app` before an `App` is defined. Try calling `Builder.load_file()` in the `build()` method of the `App`.

Another way to fix this is to use a `<ScreenManagerment>` rule in the `kv` file and then do

```
return ScreenManagement()
```

in your `build()` method.